# How to stop VAT being added to a NON VAT Line item

Tags: cognito-forms

Is it possible that after a multiple choice service type value has been selected giving a pre-VAT value of say £100.00

To follow this with a line entry with a multiple choice value of either £0.00 or £42.00 (£42 if Refundable Postal deposit option is selected) that element is not subject to VAT in the final order calculation?

Please see below:

ie, the order would be calculated as follows:

```
Service Type:   £100.00
Postal deposit: £ 42.00 - this amount is not subject to VAT
VAT             £ 20.00
Total order:    £162.00
```

Comment: This site is for users of web apps and not for developers of web apps.

Comment: @fiona: Questions about customization of Cognito Forms are generally on-topic here.

Comment: Sorry I thought it was the help system! Derr! JIM

Answer (score 1):

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) provides fine-grained control over invoice generation for [payment forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/payment) through a combination of price-aware `Choice` and `Yes/No` fields, user entered `Currency` fields, and calculation-based `Price` fields.

In particular, the [Price field](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/38/building-forms/form-field-reference/price-field) allows you to use calculations (which can include conditional logic) to assign the price, line item name, and line item description for each line item.  Price amounts can be positive or negative (such as discounts) and zero-value calculated amounts are automatically excluded.

In this case, your best bet would be to create a hidden VAT Price field that sums up all of the applicable taxable items and calculates the appropriate tax.  This VAT amount will then be added to the order automatically (as are all non-zero price field values).  If you want to show the user the taxable order total, you could calculate this first using a `Calculation` field and then use this calculated amount in your VAT price calculation.